# Add where clause to relations table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a question. This query gets me the needed data and that includes the related table `delivery`

```
$RS = $this->instance->user()->with(['driver.trailer', 'driver.truck', 'driver.delivery']);
```

I researched this topic, and I think part below should do the trick, but I don't know how to combine the two together.

```
 //add WHERE clause to driver.delivery:
->whereBetween('created_at', [
 Carbon\Carbon::parse('last monday')->startOfDay(),
 Carbon\Carbon::parse('next sunday')->endOfDay(),])
->get();
```

I am new to Laravel (doing it for about 10 days now) and this concept is very new to me. (I have no issues writing a standard query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
return $this->instance->user()->with(['driver.delivery' => function($query){
        $query->whereBetween('created_at', [ 
            Carbon\Carbon::parse('last monday')->startOfDay(),
            Carbon\Carbon::parse('next sunday')->endOfDay() ]);
    }])->with(['driver.trailer' 'driver.truck'])->get();
```